# I have allowed (smth) vs. I have been allowed (smth)

Tags: english-to-german

If I am correct

*I have allowed smth* would be rendered in German as *Ich habe etwas gedurft*

and

*I have been allowed smth* would be rendered as *Ich bin etwas gedurft worden*.

Are these correct? If not, I'm always willing to improve myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is **incorrect**, because the meaning changes. *You are allowing something*, but your translation means that *you have been allowed for something*, this would be:

> Ich habe etwas erlaubt

The second is **incorrect** too (sentence structure), this should be something like that:

> Ich habe etwas machen dürfen
>
> Ich habe etwas gedurft (used rarely)
>
> Mir wurde etwas erlaubt

Comment: Thank you. So _dürfen_ is already implicitly passive in meaning, as it means _to be allowed_, while _erlauben_ is the verb that can properly be translated into English as _to allow_. Am I correct this time?

Comment: yes you are correct this time ;)

Comment: Thanks! So, if I want to use _dürfen_ for my second example, the correct way of translating it would be _Ich habe etwas gedurft_, would it not?

Comment: Gramatically it would be correct, but it doesnt sound very nice. "gedurft" you use/hear very rarely. Alternatively i would suggest you to use `Ich habe etwas machen dürfen`

Comment: Thank you! So glad it _is_ correct. But why do you say it doesn't sound "very nice"? I mean, if you look _dürfen_ up in the dictionary (www.collinsdictionaries.com, to be exact), you will see the almost exact example given: _er hat nicht gedurft_. Anyway, many thanks for your explanations!

Comment: Because i never heard it, it's hard to explain why it doesnt sound nice, that's just a feeling you have in a language ;) When i first saw your question i wasn't even sure if this word exists. PS: Mark as an answer if you havn't any further questions

Comment: Please tell me how to mark it as an answer because I don't know how. I've only been here one day.

Comment: "Ich habe etwas gedurft (used rarely)" This is equivalent to "Ich durfte". And here it's more common that German native speaker use the simple past. Actually, this is even the most common way to say "I was allowed to do sth". I guess "Mir wurde erlaubt..." is a somewhat formal. "Ich habe machen dürfen" sounds quite odd although technically correct.

Comment: Perhaps _Ich habe tun dürfen_ sounds better?

Comment: Both your irrititations are due to a mistak in the first comment. `dürfen` is *not* implicitly passive. You just translated it by a passive construction in English. Correct would be: `dürfen` is a modal verb, and as such behaves differently than usual verbs. Most important aspect here: In spoken or casual language, modal verbs are rather used in Präteritum than Perfekt. That's why indoxica's propositions sound odd.

Comment: Both Em1 and Toscho are right. In addition, people tend to avoid using the past participle _gedurft_ because of the phrase _seine Notdurft verrichten_ (to relieve oneself) which is considered an unpleasant association to evoke.